# All navigation/voting broken in mobile on SO

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, voting, mobile-web

This morning the vote arrows are broken for me on SO for mobile web running chrome on Android. I cannot up or down vote any answers or questions.

None of the top nav works either. If I try to click inbox or recent rep, nothing happens. Clicking on hamburger takes me to SE home page (not SO home page).

The bottom nav links are also broken. I tried to click `full site` to test, but it wouldn't do anything either.

If I try to add a comment, then it just zooms to the top of the page.

I noticed there was a problem with the banner dismissing a couple days ago, so I'm guessing this might be related to that fix.

Voting seems to still work on this site, just not SO.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Works for me ...

Comment: Can you confirm if this is still an issue? It looks like a downstream cache from us went haywire and then got fixed. Would like confirmation that the site now works for you.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283273/245360

Comment: @Oded confirmed fixed, thanks!