# Error "ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined"

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I am getting this error in this console when loading pages:

```
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
```

The side effect is that these are not working:

- Inbox
- Reputation changes
- Vote up or down

This is happening with Firefox and Internet Explorer. Help?

Comment: Looks like some JavaScript has failed to load. Possibly a badly cached version between you and us.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: No repro for me BTW, if that helps

Comment: I can repro on both SO and multiple beta sites. I do not have the issue here on MSE. This is on FF 48. I have cleared my cache on the affected sites with no change.

Comment: @Oded clearing cache is not helping :(

Comment: What is rev saying in the footer @Andy

Comment: SO: `rev 2016.8.11.3879`, MSE: `rev 2016.8.11.4869`, Beta Site (Hardware Recs in this case): `rev 2016.8.11.3879`.

Comment: Can you load this file: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=2eca9bea41df ?

Comment: Can you confirm your ISP?

Comment: @Oded the problem seems to have gone away

Comment: Looks like a downstream cache from us went haywire and then got fixed.

Comment: Just for reference - have a look at your browser extensions. Had the same problem, Ghostery blocked jQuery from Google servers.